# Suggested Edits - Improving ONLY the tags

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I've just earned enough reputation to start reviewing the suggested edits. Awesome! So I've started to work my way through the edits list.

However, I've come across a large number of suggested edits that the only edit is suggesting a new tag. At first I didn't see this as an issue until I realised that it was just the same people going onto post after post adding this single tag.

In my opinion, this is not improving the original post in any way? So these users are getting lots of +2 rep for quite pointless edits.

In my opinion I feel I should be rejecting these sort of edits?

What is the best way to deal with these? Should I reject them or approve them as I suppose they're adding a relevant tag.

***For example:***

[image: Edit Example]

Comment: There are quite a few bots that submit such edits, fully automated by searching for a specific tag or keyword and add another one. It's an easy way to get 2000 rep in a few days. </hypothesis>

Comment: @Floern Well, a potentially easy way to get _1000_ rep in a few days. Once you've gained 1000 from suggested edits, you don't gain any more.